# Error al llamar a metodo fetchAll Php

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Tengo el siguiente código en PHP, y al intentar hacer cualquier consulta a la base de datos me aparece un error. Este es mi codigo de prueba

```
$objeto = new ProviderRopa("comprasropa");
    $conexion = $objeto->getConnection();
    
    $result = $conexion->prepare("select top 1 * from cat_articulos");
    $respuesta = $result->execute();
    
     $response = $respuesta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    
    var_dump($response);
```

El mensaje de error es el siguiente: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in

Estuve leyendo y puede ser cuando la consulta regresa false, pero hice un var_dump de la variable respuesta y regresa true, además hice la prueba en la consulta haciendo un update y si lo realizó correctamente en la base de datos, cual es el error que tengo? no puedo identificarlo.

Gracias

Comment: El problema es que si es true, donde tienes que hacer el fetchall es en $result y no en $respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes una confusión al nombrar los objetos.

PDO funciona así:  en tu caso, `$result` es el objeto que se ha preparado. Debes por tanto usar ese objeto para el `execute()`, como de hecho haces,  pero **también** para el `fetchAll()`. Y cuando aplicas el `execute()` no tienes necesidad de guardar lo ocurrido en una variable.

Así debería funcionar:

```
$result = $conexion->prepare("select top 1 * from cat_articulos");
$result->execute();
$response = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
var_dump($response);
```

Como ves, se usará `$result` en todo, porque ese es el objeto que se prepararó, el que se ejecutó y el que tendrá los resultados que obtendrás con el método `fetch...`

Comment: Gracias, tienes razón